# ASP.NET Core MVC app on ECR has Google OAuth issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth, amazon-ecr

I have published an ASP.NET Core MVC app to ECS. The app has Google login. It works fine on my local. But it gives 500 error on AWS.

Here is my codes

```
_ = app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            context.Request.Host = new HostString("www.***.com");
            context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            await next();
        });
```

WebApplication extensions;

```
        _ = app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions() {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        _ = app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        _ = app.UseStaticFiles();
        _ = app.UseRouting();

        _ = app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions() {
            CheckConsentNeeded = context => true,
            HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax
        });

        _ = app.UseAuthorization();

        _ = app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );
```

ServiceConfiguration extensions;

```
        _ = services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options => {
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        _ = services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;

        });
```

ServiceConfiguration extensions;

```
        _ = services
            .AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options => {
                options.ClientId = _options.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = _options.ClientSecretId;
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;

                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = (context) => {
                    var picture = context.User.GetProperty("picture").GetString();
                    picture ??= "";
                    context.Identity?.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", picture));
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });
```

I have an ALB on AWS.
HTTPS listener redirects to my target group.
HTTP listener redirects to HTTPS:443

First "Authorized redirect URIs" was empty on Google console. It was showing following error (as excepted)

[image]

Then I have added `https://localhost:7091/signin-google` and `https://www.***.com/signin-google`. Then it started to give following error on AWS only. It is working on local.

[image]

And here is logs from ECS

```
    July 29, 2023 at 15:35 (UTC+3:00)   [12:35:34 ERR] Connection id "0HMSG550MHDGT", Request id "0HMSG550MHDGT:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.    
    July 29, 2023 at 15:35 (UTC+3:00)   System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login. 
    July 29, 2023 at 15:35 (UTC+3:00)   ---> System.Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: redirect_uri_mismatch;Description=Bad Request  
    July 29, 2023 at 15:35 (UTC+3:00)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  
    July 29, 2023 at 15:35 (UTC+3:00)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()   
    July 29, 2023 at 15:35 (UTC+3:00)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) 
    July 29, 2023 at 15:35 (UTC+3:00)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)    
    July 29, 2023 at 15:35 (UTC+3:00)   [12:35:34 WRN] The cookie '.AspNetCore.Correlation.9z-hyr8Tyg3iwF3avCY7szkU_TozjPW2hUSebLjmpzo' has set 'SameSite=None' and must also set 'Secure'. 
    July 29, 2023 at 15:35 (UTC+3:00)   [12:35:31 INF] ExternalLogin > Provider: Google Return: /Client 
    July 29, 2023 at 15:35 (UTC+3:00)   [12:35:31 INF] ExternalLogin > challenging: RedirectUri: '/Auth/ExternalLoginCallback?returnUrl=%2FClient'Items [Key: '.redirect' Value: .redirect, Key: 'LoginProvider' Value: LoginProvider, ]Parameters []
```

What am I missing?